# Apache NiFi with Websocket stream of Google Flatbuffers payloads

Tags: apache-nifi

Has something like this been done before? If not, what would be involved in getting  NiFi to ingest a stream arriving over a WebSocket with Google FlatBuffers?

(would a simple TCP stream make it easier or harder?)

---

**UPDATE**

I have a C++ program that is running on a node, which is collecting data and publishing it via nanomessage pub/sub channel over a websocket. The data in C++ looks like structs, and I am serializing it with Google Flatbuffers. It is a very simple struct, think of csv records. We have a team member who wants to capture this data with NiFi and put it to a database.

Personally, since Flatbuffers supports conversion of binary to JSON, I think this is almost easier just writing a short C#, python, java or javascript program to receive the flabuffers, open a DB connection, and dump the data. (maybe convert to JSON first, if needed).

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? Do you have another web service with a WebSocket-based API you wish to invoke from NiFi, or is it instead that you want NiFi to present a WebSocket interface that a client could invoke to create a connection and then start streaming entities? Both should be possible. This may be helpful: http://ijokarumawak.github.io/nifi/2016/11/04/nifi-websocket. For parsing flatbuffers, you may have to use a custom processor or ExecuteScript.

Comment: @kevdoran , see update

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge, NiFi does not have an integration with the nanomsg library/protocol out of the box. This would likely require writing a custom processor for that is capable of consuming nanomsg packets using the nanomsg PUBSUB pattern / socket types.

One could use existing processors, such as the `Consume*` processors (`ConsumeKafka`, `ConsumeJMS`) as an example / guide for how to write a processor that consumes messages from a topic/queue that follows the pub/sub pattern.

You would then want to transform the payload from Flatbuffers binary to a format insertable into the desired database. Again, a custom processor using code generated from your Flatbuffer schema would probably be the right approach for that.

As you mention, this could also be accomplished with a simple program. If you wrote that program in Java (using the Java nanomsg and flatbuffers libs) as a prototype/proof-of-concept, then it could be refactored into one or more NiFi custom processors in the future if you wish to move to NiFi.